# Providing a default value to a parameter that uses ArgumentCompletions attribute

Tags: powershell

Here is a distilled version of my function:

```
function Get-CommandBar{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias("GCom")]
    Param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Path = $pwd,
        [Parameter()]
        [ArgumentCompletions('Path', 'Copy')]
        $ActiveTab = 'Path',
        [Switch]$ActiveVideo,
        [Switch]$AllTabs
        )
    
        begin{
            
                
        }
        process {
            Switch ($PSBoundParameters.Keys){
                'ActiveTab'{ 
                    If ($ActiveTab -eq "Path"){
                        "Path"
                    }elseif($ActiveTab -eq "Copy"){
                        "Copy"
                    }
                }
                'AllTabs'{
                    "All Tabs"
                }
                'ActiveVideo'{
                    "Active Video"
    
                }
         }
        }
}
```

`get-CommandBar -ActiveTab Path` outputs:

```
Path
```

`get-CommandBar -ActiveTab Copy` outputs:

```
Copy
```

But trying just `get-CommandBar -ActiveTab`, instead of `Path`, it outputs an error:

```
Get-CommandBar: Missing an argument for parameter 'ActiveTab'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Object' and try again.
```

What gives? Shouldnt `$ActiveTab = 'Path'` be sufficient? Information on `ArgumentCompletions` seems to be sparse out here.m
Any help would be wonderfull.

Comment: If you want to use the default value, don't specify `-ActiveTab` at all. Specifying a (non-switch) parameter name syntactically requires an argument.

Comment: I see, I will have rethink the design in this then, as I had something else in mind for when just `Get-CommandBar` is invoked. More importantly I wanted to understand this argumentcompletion thing. Thanks mklement0